# Thymeleaf: convert a list of objects to JSON when fields' name should contains a dash

Tags: json, highcharts, thymeleaf

I have a simple class like the following:

```
public class Item {
    private final String hcKey;
    private final int value;
    public Item(String hcKey, int value) {
        this.hcKey = hcKey;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getHcKey()
}
```

I create a `List<Item>` and I pass it as an attribute to ThymeLeaf template to feed data into a Highchart map chart:

```
 List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(new Item("xyz", 5), ... );
 model.addAttribute("entries", items);
 return "chart";
```

On my HTML page, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
$(function () {
    var data = [[${entries}]];
    ...
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Notice that, if I execute the MVC service, the attribute is properly expanded:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
$(function () {
    var data = [{'hcKey':'xyz','value':5}, ... ];
    ...
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

And eventually, the question!

Highchairs unfortunately expects the name of the first field to be `hc-key`, but the dash is not a valid character for field names in Java. What can I do to automatically obtain the following?

```
...
var data = [{'hc-key':'xyz','value':5}, ... ];
...           ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map these options (keys) in JavaScript, for example:

```
var data = [[${entries}]].map(function(item) {
    item['hc-key'] = item.hcKey;
    return item;
});
```

Comment: Hi Pawel, thanks for your suggestion. I understand that your solution works, but my JS is terrible: aren't we adding a whole new pair of strings for each item of the list, wasting some memory? I guess if it's not possible to do the conversion with Thymeleaf straightly, your solution is a good compromise!

Comment: That is correct, we duplicate that values. You can also remove old property using `delete item.hcKey;` to keep the memory. Unfortunately, I don't know Thymeleaf, so I can not help you there :)